# How to authenticate react .net-core web app using AAD?

Tags: .net-core, react-redux, azure-active-directory

i have created react .net-core webapp and trying to implement Azure ad authentication . Do i need to implement seperate authentication for frontend and backend ? can i use authentication token generated using front end library to authenticate backend code and vice versa. Any help appreciated.

Comment: There's a sample app for that here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-spa-dotnetcore-webapi-obo

Answer (score 1):

As @juunas mentioned sample demonstrates a React single-page application that lets a user authenticate and then obtain an access token to call an ASP.NET Core Web API, protected by Azure AD. The Web API then calls the MS Graph API on the user's behalf using the on-behalf-of flow.

[image]

please refer to this [simple](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-spa-dotnetcore-webapi-obo)